# objective c++ accessing an NSSlider from c++ callback

Tags: cocoa, objective-c++

AppController.h

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {

}

@property (retain) IBOutlet NSSlider * mySlider;

void setMySlider (NSSlider *ns);// c function
```

AppController.m

```
@implementation AppController

int myAmount=0;
@synthesize mySlider;


void setMySlider(NSSlider *mySlider){

    [ns setIntValue:10]; //ok
    ns.intValue =myAmount;//ok
}

myCallBackFunction(double delta,std::vector<unsigned char>*myData,void *userData){

myAmount=50;
 NSLog(@"%i", myAmount); // ok does display value of myAmount

// should move my slider the value of my amount by calling the following C function:

changeSliderVelocity(mySlider);// error message mySlider was not declared in this scope

}
```

Comment: Please write out your question clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In this case, even though `myCallBackFunction()` is placed between `@implementation` and `@end` it is not within the class scope of `AppController`.  The `int myAmount` is like a static Class-ish Member (I have actually no idea what its scope is.  Global??) because you defined it in the Implementation file, it is not actually part of the object `AppController`.

No guarantees this will work, but give it a shot.  It assumes there will only ever be 1 (one) instance of AppController.  Read up more on Singletons in Obj-C/C++.

```
@implementation AppController

static AppController *sharedAppInstance = nil;

- (void) init
{
  // ... whatever other code you have
  if (sharedAppInstance == nil)

     sharedAppController = self; //error message sharedAppController was not declared in //this scope. So I replaced the line sharedAppController = self; by:

       sharedAppInstance= self;

}

myCallBackFunction(double delta,std::vector<unsigned char>*myData,void *userData){

changeSliderVelocity([[AppController sharedAppInstance] mySlider]); // Replace this line with to make it work:
changeSliderVelocity([sharedAppInstance mySlider]);//ok does work.

}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response STEPHEN I've tried your code but it came out with an error message: sharedAppController not declared in scope. I'm trying to use cocoa just for the GUI. myCallbackFunction set the global variable myAmount to 50 which it does fine and update the position of the slider or display the value myAmount in to an NSTextField which i'm having problem with.As soon as i try to access cocoa object, i'm having problems(error not declared in this scope).

Comment: @boubacar mamadou, Try this instead: `[[AppController sharedAppInstance] mySlider]`

Comment: Thank U very much Stephen You pointed me in the right direction. The key was to create the init function and set sharedAppInstance to self and in the callback, accessing sharedAppInstance mySlider through the c function changeSliderVelocity.I changed 2 line in your code, feel free to have look. I've been trying to solve this problem for the past 3 weeks with no success.Once again Thank u very much for your help could not have done it without it.

Comment: Srephen how do you accept an answer? I'm new to the site and can't find the accept answer option.

Comment: hi Stephen i think i that i accepted your answer as correct I clicked on a check box on the left hand of your answer and it did turn green